# Data retreived by Mysql server

Tags: javascript, mysql

I'm trying to develop an app only in JavaScript in the browser. I'm trying to access a MySQL server and get data from there using asynchronous requests. 
I would like to know whats the protocol and the format of the data retrieved from a MySQL server to the client, in order to know if it its possible to develop my own lib to parse the data.

Comment: Generally people don'e open up the database directly to Internet-sourced queries, and instead use a layer of server code to provide authentication and authorization services.

Comment: You can't... JavaScript doesn't support this. You can only communicate with a server using HTTP (i.e. Ajax request or by using the browser's usual methods like clicking on a link or submitting a form). Even if you could do it, consider the fact that any JavaScript code you include in a page is automatically public, viewable through the browser's developer tools. Therefore anyone could immediately steal the password to your database by reading the code.

Comment: So you need some server side API code as an intermediary between the browser and the database, and to do things like authentication, data validation and any other business logic which should not be tampered with by the client - again bear in mind that any JavaScript you include in a page can be altered or even removed by someone with a small amount of knowledge. The browser-web API- database structure is a standard web application architecture the world over, and that will need to be your approach here.

Comment: The question is whats the protocol mysql server uses to recive requests and send response? Is it http? because if its the case then you can send the same information that would be sent by, for instance, the JDBCdriver, or the one PHP uses.